# Enqueue and Dequeue in efficiency O(1)

Tags: c#, queue, nodes

I am implementing a Queue class in C# using a Node/LinkedList class that I also implemented, and I wonder if there is a way to implement the enqueue and the dequeue methods, both in algorithmic efficiency of O(1).

In the Queue class I have a field of the tail and the head, and I managed to implement the enqueue method in O(1), but the dequeue is O(n).

This is the code for the dequeue method:

```
public T Dequeue()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue is empty");
    T data = head.Data;
    if (tail == null)
    {
        head = null;
        return data;
    }
    Node<T> temp = tail;

    while (temp.Next != head)
        temp = temp.Next;

    temp.Next = null;
    head = temp;
    if (tail == head)
        tail = null;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You provided no code to help you with. But anyway, this question is more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dymanoid I added some code.

Comment: If you keep a `tail` pointer, then when you enqueue, just append to the tail. And dequeue from the `head`. Both operations are O(1).

Comment: @JimMischel how can I  from the head? I need to know the previous node of the head, so I need to find it by moving forward from the tail.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a circular queue?

Comment: @JimMischel no.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain a head reference and a tail reference, then you can enqueue at the tail, and dequeue at the head, both in O(1). Here's the basic idea. You'll have to convert to C#:

```
head = null
tail = null

enqueue(node)
    node.next = null;  // this will be the final node in the list
    if (head == null)
        head = node
        tail = node
    else
        tail.next = node
    tail = node

dequeue()
    if (head == null)
        error: queue is empty

    result = head     // dequeue from the front

    head = head.next  // head now points to the next node
    if (head == null)
        tail = null   // if head is null, then there are no more nodes

    return result
```

The key here is that, except when the list is empty, adding a node at the end doesn't need to affect `head`. And since you have a `tail` pointer, you don't need to go searching for the end of the list.

Similarly, removing a node from the front doesn't need to affect `tail`, unless you remove the last node.

When I first started working with linked lists, I found it helpful to lay out some playing cards to represent the nodes, and toothpicks between them to represent the links. Then, I'd add, move, or remove toothpicks to simulate the operations of inserting and removing nodes. It really helped to solidify the concepts in my mind.